# Restart MongoDB Replica Set

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I tried to search but most of the solutions are very old, and I feel there will be a better solution available which I am unable to find.

#### Problem

I created the replica set, and it's working. I tried to connect my docker backed application, and it was connecting to it.

Later I changed the **dbpath** from `dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb` to the new path `dbpath=/data/mongodb`. I didn't restart the replica set after this change.

I ran my backend application and it couldn't connect to the replica set. I think its because I didn't restart the MogoDB ReplicaSet.  I am using **Mongo version 4.4.5**

I want to restart the MongoDB Replica Set to check if this can solve the issue.
My connection string :

```
mongodb://username:pwd@prod-privateIP-1:27017,prod-privateIP-2:27017,prod-privateIP-3:27017/prodDB?replicaSet=replica1&authSource=admin
```

What is the best practice/recommended approach to restart the MongoDB Replica Set ?

Comment: In general, restarting a replica-set involves stopping each the member of the set (do some maintenance or changes) and restarting the member. This is dome one member at a time.

Comment: If you changed the dbpath without restarting, it probably continued to use the old path.

Comment: @prasad_ Is it correct approach [**here**](http://www.tutorial-points.com/2016/03/stopping-and-starting-mongodb.html). What about `Master` node? Don't we stop it and restart ?

Comment: When you shutdown and restart a node an election will be triggered _and_ a new primary may be elected. There is no guarantee that the same primary will become primary again. This also depends upon factors like the _priority_ for a member - higher priority members are likely to become primary nodes. (Please note that I cannot say what is correct (or not) about the link you had posted in your comment.)

Comment: @prasad_ `When you shutdown and restart a node an election will be triggered and a new primary may be elected`, can you please refer to a doc? Thanks.

Comment: See [rs.add](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/rs.add/#behavior) method.